# How to structure moveable objects with MVC pattern?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, drag-and-drop

I'm developing an iOS app that allows users to drag and drop images around a screen as a part of one of its features (note — not the iOS 11 drag between apps). Each image is a custom model `Photo`, and then a `Page` model object has an array of `Photo`s.

I was thinking of having a `PageEditor` view that contains all of the `Photo` objects, but I'm not sure, then, how to best keep track of the x/y positioning of each object. Because the `Photo` object is a struct, not a view, I need to have each `Photo` object also have a custom `PhotoView` that is draggable.

So essentially, a `PageEditor` has a `Page` which has `Photo`s. But a `PageEditor` also has an array of `PhotoView`s, so which model/view should know its positioning?

I appreciate this is quite an abstract question.

Comment: Sorry, but that's why you down-vote. *Be more clear.* Maybe try to (a) not be vague, and (b) give us something specific enough we can reproduce. Here's what I read from your vague question - how do you track the frame origin of an array of "photos" or `UIImages` stored in `UIImageViews` (but not necessarily in the same array) because you have something called a `PageEditor`. I have no idea how close I am - but without some code I hope you can see just how "abstract" **and** vague your question is! Good luck.

Comment: @dfd I'm not sure how to be more clear. I have a ViewController that relies on a model object that in turn has an array of model objects. You can't move around models. You can only move views. So, should the underlying model of each view know its position? OR should only the view know its x / y coordinates?

Comment: Could you post some code in your question? What's the reason a view controller needs to know any subview coordinates? What is you are trying to accomplish? Moving a subview in it's superview is (1) something can be done in iOS *one at a time* - you can't be dragging two views at once - and a controller, properly wired up with gestures, already knows which view is being moved. In code, you know the gesture's view and using it's tag value, can be ID'd easily. But again, it's tough to be of help without code.

Answer (score 0):

your photo object can contain two x,y co-ordinate points. The position of the photo can be updated based on.

```
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,  with event: UIEvent)
```

inside you can access the location of your touches with

```
for touch in touches {
  touch.position(in:self)
  // update Photo x,y 
}
```

In MVC, your Photo is a model. your PhotoView is a View.